# Is it possible to create a VSTO document-level add-in and deploy having only one executable (docx) file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vba, ms-word, vsto

My problem is the following: in Visual Studio 2013 I created a .docx file and I've written a really basic code to the StartUp() method. (it downloads another text file from a specified webpage, so I'm using a web_client. It works just fine if I start if from Visual Studio or from the solution folder.
But the problem is, that Visual Studio creates a .vsto file in the solution folder as well and if I copy the .docx file somewhere else, the code won't run. (the document itself loads anyway)
How can I manage it to get only 1 .docx file with the code in it. So I won't need the vsto file or anything else file.
Thanks in advance!